# can i use power over ethernet with a cat 6 cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, wireless-access-point, wired-networking

I have a network switch that can provide Poe and I plan to use it to power an access point at my house. do I need to use any special cable to power the access point using Poe or will a cat6 cable suffice?

Comment: it is unclear what problem you are having ... POE is used for sending power over unmodified ethernet cables ... please use web browser to research this before you ask a question here

Answer (score 0):

PoE works over standard cables - category 5 or better for gigabit 1000BASE-T.